# Small speaker with full frequency range?

Tags: acoustics, frequency, electronics, electrical-engineering

As I understand Hi-Fi headphones are usually small in diameter and support full range like from 20 to 20 000 Hz.
But when I try to buy small loudspeaker I see that they do not support low frequencies at all and start from about 80.

Is it theoretically possible to make the loudspeaker with 7 cm diameter that supports full frequency response from 20 to 20 000 Hz?

I need not it to be very loud, it should work at the half meter distance.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get a 7cm speaker to radiate up to about 8kHz. Above that, the response will diminish rapidly because the mass of the speaker cone inhibits its ability to accelerate fast enough to radiate well up there. You need a smaller speaker (called a *tweeter*) in tandem, connected through a *crossover network*, with the 7cm to reach to 20kHz.

A 7cm speaker will easily move in response to a 20Hz signal but its *radiation resistance* will be very low at that frequency, meaning it will not produce very much sound there. In addition, your ears are not very sensitive to 20Hz sound waves, so any sound the speaker produces there will be hard to hear. To remedy this requires electronically boosting the low frequency signals with an *equalizer* or cupping the speaker very closely to your ear (as in a pair of large, acoustically sealed headphones) or increasing the diameter of the loudspeaker.

20Hz response loud enough to hear in an open room (no headphones) usually requires a specialized speaker called a *woofer* which is capable of very large cone movements (of order ~ 2cm!) and of diameter between 30 and 45cm, and an applied power of from tens to hundreds of watts from the amplifier.

However, note that because most recorded music contains very little program information below 80Hz and above 12kHz, and because most recorded music is played back at amplifier power levels of less than 20 watts, you can obtain very good results with a two-speaker arrangement consisting of a 25cm woofer in conjunction with a 3cm tweeter (called a *two-way system*) and a 20 watt/channel amplifier.

Comment: 30 cm woofer at maximum power I will easily hear at the distance of 10 meters. What should be the size of woofer to reproduce 20 Hz at the distance of 0.5 meters ?

Comment: I do not know! try a long-excursion 12" "subwoofer" at 50 watts.

Comment: I mean can it be smaller if I need it only for short distance ?

Comment: yes it can 25cm is worth trying.

Comment: So is your answer like 20 Hz at 7 cm loudspeaker is theoretically impossible ?

Comment: No, it is that 20Hz at 7 cm loudspeaker will require long cone excursions and lots of electrical power.